# How to execute .bat file without opening console window using wix custiom action

Tags: wix, wix3

Am executing .bat file in custom action using wix. When i run the set up it successfully exceuting .bat file but with console window. I don't want any console window. It is possibe to hide window using wix or with .bat file.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: I've seen a *lot* of installers from even quite big organizations where command prompt windows briefly flash open and closed. I'm not sure you can entirely prevent them.

Comment: what should i mention in .bat file to flash open and closed

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
start program args
exit
```

but this will open command line window for just a moment, until the program starts, afterwhich it closes. Alternatively, and equivalently, you can do:

```
Start ""  "program args"
```

So, to start notepad and then exit the cmd terminal, you'd do:

```
start notepad
exit
```

or:

```
Start "" "notepad"
```

Comment: where should i use this code in .bat file which am exceuting from custom action

Comment: If by custom action you mean that you're just running some program with certain arguments, then you can put that in between the double quotes, instead of notepad, if going with the second method above.

Comment: yeah am running .bat file to create sharepoint site. am passing parameters from exec

Comment: here is my code sample     <CustomAction Id="CA_SITECREATION" Impersonate="no" ExeCommand='"[SCRIPT_LOC]SiteCreation.bat" "[WEBAPPNAME]" "" "[PORTNUMBER]"  "[SITEOWNER]"' Directory="SCRIPT_LOC" Execute="deferred" Return="check"  />

Comment: I tried the above thing but it's not working the command window is not closing until the execution completes !!!!

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a new text file with a .vbs extension, for example, run_invisible.vbs.
2. Open the .vbs file with a text editor and add the following code:

`Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell") objShell.Run "Your_bat_file_path", 0, True`
Replace "your_batch_file.bat" with the path to your actual batch file.

3. Save the .vbs file.
4. now you can double click the .vbs file(not the .bat file) to run your batch file without displaying the console window.